# How to use Stackato

Tags: stackato

I have part of my team using komodo, and so I have looked into Stackato. At first Stackato looked nice, but I can not figure out how to use it. It is available for download as a VM image. You can also deploy it to an existing infrastructure. But what is the point of this. Most cloud platforms I've used(Bluemix, PWS, Openshift, etc...) are in a cloud instance, but Stackato does not seem to do this. Do I have to use Stackato with some infrastructure, or can I get a in-cloud version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "in a cloud instance" you mean offered as a hosted service (like Heroku, Engine Yard, and Google App Engine) then you could try the [Stackato Sandbox](http://www.activestate.com/stackato/sandbox) which is a hosted trial environment.

That said, the real benefit of Stackato is that it's PaaS software that you can run yourself (i.e. "Private PaaS"), so to really get a feel for it from an Admin/Provider's perspective, you should deploy a small cluster in a public cloud like [HP Helion Public Cloud](http://docs.stackato.com/admin/server/hpcs.html) or [Amazon EC2](https://www.activestate.com/blog/2014/10/your-own-stackato-cluster-amazon-ec2).

Yes, you can run it on your own servers, but I think the cloud hosted option what you're looking for. You can run a cluster of around 5 Stackato nodes with a free license from ActiveState, but the cloud hosting costs still apply.

Comment: Interesting, but would it not be cheaper and give you better control just to use the infrastructure as-is?

Comment: Probably not cheaper unless you're already using Docker or LXC to run multiple apps per host. You might have a *little* more control (though buildpacks provide a lot of configurability) if you set up your virtual machines manually for each app you're deploying/hosting. That defeats the purpose of Platform-as-a-Service though. The idea is to set up the platform once, then deploy whatever kind of applications you want and the platform handles setup.